# Beautiful 'folding' pattern in the decimal expansion of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{10^{2^n}-1}=\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{99}+\frac{1}{9999}+\dots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

In the decimal expansion of the following infinite sum (number of $9$s is doubled in each term) we get a beautiful pattern: $$x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{10^{2^n}-1}=\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{99}+\frac{1}{9999}+\dots$$

$$x=0.1213121412131215121312141213121\dots$$

$$x=0.\color{blue}{1}2\color{blue}{1}\dots$$

$$x=0.\color{blue}{121}3\color{blue}{121}\dots$$

$$x=0.\color{blue}{1213121}4\color{blue}{1213121}\dots$$

$$x=0.\color{blue}{121312141213121}5\color{blue}{121312141213121}\dots$$

This number shows a perfect pattern until it's $2^9=512$th digit, when $10$ should appear for the first time, and of course it messes the pattern up because it contains two digits instead of $1$.

> I get why this happens intuitively, but how *exactly* does this pattern appear?
>
> Will we get a similar pattern in any base $b$ for the sum $x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{b^{2^n}-1}$?

Comment: $1/(10^{2^n}-1)=0.\overline{0\dots 01}$ with period $2^n$, i.e. we get an additional $1$ every $2^n$ digits. For just the same reason the pattern will hold in every base, and will eventually break for every base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that

$$\begin{align} 
1/9=&\ 0.111111111...,\\
1/99=&\ 0.010101010...,\\
1/9999=&\ 0.000100010....
\end{align}$$

Sum them. At every decimal place you get a $1$ from $1/9$; at every $2n$ th decimal you add an extra $1$ because of $1/99$; and at every $4n$ th decimal you add even one more extra $1$ because of $1/9999$. You hence get

$$1/9+1/99+1/9999=0.121312131...$$

Now adding more terms will produce the pattern you saw.